# Conceptual problem in Noetherian rings and Zorn Lemma

Tags: ring-theory, axiom-of-choice, noetherian

I've got a problem, and it's that I can't see the difference of one of the definitions of Noetherian ring, and supposing the zorn lemma for that ring.

I mean, if I use the definition of the maximal element in every non-empty set of ideals it's clear to me that if I suppose the zorn lemma as true, every ring becomes (For me) a "Weakly-noetherian ring", and I become able to prove some properties that before I only could with noetherians.

But when I use the definition of the ascending chain which terminates, I can't see the difference. I mean, if I have an ascending chain, and it terminates, it'd have a maximal element... and **if it has a maximal element it should terminate.** But that wouldn't be possible, because if we suppose Zorn lemma with my bold statement we would get that every ring is noetherian... and I already have seen some non-noetherian rings so...

I think there would be a mistake in the reasoning in bold... but I can't locate it...

Is there any chain which has a maximal element, and doesn't terminate? Is there something else I'm not seeing and I should?

Comment: You want to show that each chain has an upper bound. If this is true, then by Zorn's lemma, you have a maximal element.

Comment: Well, I wasn't trying to show anything, I just got confused with the definitions...

Comment: There is a difference between upper bound and maximal element. A chain can have an upper bound that is not an element of the chain itself.

Comment: As an example of a non-terminating increasing chain of ideals, think about a polynomial ring over $\mathbf Q$ in infinitely many variables $x_1, x_2, ...$ There is an infinite non-terminating chain $(x_1) \subsetneq (x_1, x_2) \subsetneq ...$ all contained within the maximal ideal $(x_1, x_2, ...)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not every set of ideals has a maximal elements.

It is true that with the axiom of choice, the set of *all* ideals has a maximal element, but it is not true that *every* set of ideals has a maximal element.

For example, look at $\Bbb Z[\{x_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}]$ and consider the set of ideals which are generated by $\{x_i\mid i<n\}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. This set of ideals has no maximal element. But the ring itself, of course, has a maximal ideal.

Since you brought up the axiom of choice and Noetherian ideals, it should be noted that the definition "every ascending chain stabilizes" is not equivalent to "every non-empty set of ideals has a maximal element" without *some* choice. It is in fact strictly weaker.